# unable to register the HAL to hardware service manager

Tags: android, c++, hal

Hi i am checking some specific use case in that use case my HAL is running but it is not registered with hardware service manager.

In my HAL service file i am adding my HAL into the hardware service manager in main function but it is not the added into the HwServiceManager.

Use Case performed:

1. run stop command.
2. wait for 5-6 seconds.
3. run start command.

**stop command will stop the zygote process and start will start the zygote process.**

**output looks similar to this:**

----------------------------------------HAL Name-------------------------------Thread Use-------server------client 
OEM.XXX.hardware.OEM_HAL@1.0::IOEM_HAL/default-----------N/A------------------N/A--------

IMPORTANT:
I can't tell you the HAL service name and the output as it is OEM specific changes.

Comment: How do Zygote and HAL implementations correlate? What stop/start commands are you using (`setprop ctl.stop "oemhal_1_0"`?). Please also check your `logcat` output for related entries (e.g. anything that contains your HAL interface name or service name).